# Downloaded image size for UIImageView for retina vs non-retina display

Tags: ios8, uiimageview, xcode7

I am setting UIImageView's image to a download image.  I can specify the size of the image I am downloading - should I check the screen resolution and download the image at @2x or @3x size for retina display and @1x for non-retina? How do people usually handle this?

For example, if the UIImageView's size is 100x100, should I download 200x200 for iPhone 6 and 300x300 for iPhone 6s?